# What is the equivalent Collation type in Oracle for the Latin1_General_BIN collation type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, collation

I am in the process of migrating a SQL Server database to Oracle and would like to know the collation equivalent in Oracle for Latin1_General_BIN .

It would be great help if someone could help me with the syntax to set collations in Oracle .

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Collation refers to how the database stores and sorts data.

**SQL Server**

Latin1_General = U.S. English character set (code page 1252).

_BIN = Sorts/compares data based on bit patterns of each character. Sort order is case-sensitive; lowercase precedes uppercase, and accent-sensitive.  This is the fastest sorting order.

**Oracle**

NLS_LANG specifies the Oracle character set as WE8MSWIN1252 which maps to my Windows ANSI code page 1252.

and an NLS_SORT of BINARY
You do **not** want to choose the options with suffix of _CI (case insensitivity) or _AI (accent-insensitive and case-insensitive).

Answer (score 0):

NLS_LANG  is just a client-side parameter.
For the database side there is many NLS_ Parameters for:
- Language support
- Territory support
- Linguistic sorting and searching
- Character sets and semantics

you have also 2 independants NLS_ parameter for character set in every database : The Database character set and the National character set